# How can you customize wp_get_archives(); with Wordpress Archives

Tags: wordpress, archive

I want to customize my archives to sort by month, but if it was in the previous year to group itself into a yearly category. Right now I have:

```
<ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&limit=10'); ?></ul>
```

That shows the last 10 posts. I know that the following will sort by month:

```
<ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?></ul>
```

But how do I get it to sort by year when the month is less recent than 12? I want it to look like the following:

- March 2010
- February 2010
- January 2010
- 2009

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a builtin way to do this, I'd use a function with custom query like this:

```
  SELECT COUNT(ID) posts, YEAR(post_date) y, MONTH(post_date) m 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
   WHERE post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY y, m
  HAVING y = YEAR(NOW())
UNION
  SELECT COUNT(ID), YEAR(post_date) y, 0
    FROM $wpdb->posts
   WHERE post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY y
  HAVING y < YEAR(NOW())
ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC;
```

then format the results with links and all.

Comment: Kemp's way to do it is the only way to do it apart from using a plugin.

Comment: I began writing my own plugin but ended up finding one that does exactly what I want. For other's interested, check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collapsing-archives/screenshots/

Comment: this also allows users to specify custom post types which don't get listed by wp_get_archives